# How To Only Retrieve Top X Items from Outlook Folder - Interop C#

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

I am writing a C# application where I want to loop through the 500 most recent emails in a given folder. The reason is because getting all the emails takes a long time using the below lines:

```
MAPIFolder folder = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
List<MailItem> items = folder.Items.OfType<MailItem>().ToList();
```

However, I know that what I am searching for each time is always going to be a recent email, so there's no need to get an entire year's worth of emails each time (over 8000, and I get less emails than the average employee at my job).

So, is there a way to only retrieve a certain amount of emails from a folder with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change your ToList() to Take(500).ToList()?

Comment: Try to combine Sort("[ReceivedTime]",true) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort and GetFirst() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.getfirst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
List<MailItem> items = folder.Items.OfType<MailItem>().ToList();
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. They allow getting only items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Instead of getting recent 500 emails you may retrieve emails for a day, few days, week and etc. So, you can process items in bunch. For example:

```
criteria = "[ReceivedTime] > '" _ 
         & Format$("6/12/20 3:30PM","General Date") & "'"
```

You may find the [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) article helpful.